# SSIS IMPORT: Excel to sql server with date columns(convert unicode string to DT_DBDATE)

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, data-conversion

Struggling with SSIS Excel Import evrything is fine except date columns that are DT_WSTR from excel source and should be DATE in destination table.

The excel columns are a general format and I have no control of this so can't edit it. The destination Table must have the correct outputs and I will be using the same package when receiving more data to add to the table.

First tried data conversion to DT_DBDATE which failed.

Don't really know how to use DERIVED COLUMN but I tried some expressions from similar cases here that didn't work:

```
 (DT_DBDATE)(MyDateColumn,1,2)+"."+SUBSTRING(MyDateColumn,3,2)+"."+SUBSTRING(MyDateColumn,5,4))
```

Then I tried ignoring errors and the date columns were copied as NULL to the table.

Lastly I tried with a script task converting OUTPUT to DT_DATE:

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
try
{ 
//repeated this for rest of Datecolumns
Row.CopyofMyDateColumn=DateTime.ParseExact(Row.MyDateColumn, "dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
Catch (Exception ex)
{
book pbCancel= false;
this.ComponentMetaData.FireError(5, "The component failed to convert the date", "Component error", string.Empty,5, out pbCancel);
}
}
```

This executes successfully but dates are now all 1899-12-30. All of them. Also added IMEX=1

My desired output is dd.MM.yyyy

Comment: Are your empty dates really null? or are they empty strings? Excel is always a tricky source.

Comment: Also can you add an image of your source? The output is a date and won't be formatted the way you want unless you want a string. You should probably load a date and do formatting on your presentation layer.

Comment: Have you changed your source date column types back to DT_WSTR? If DateTime.ParseExact() is outputting 1899-12-30 for all inputs then I'd suspect that the input columns are still set to DT_DBDATE types.

Comment: @KeithL can you please elaborate on "you should probably load a date and do formatting on your presentation layer". I currently don't have a picture of the excel doc but the date columns are of a general format

Comment: @AlwaysLearning my source columns are always DT_WSTR. In script task properties>Input output> Output i changed the data type to DT_DATE, i had tried with DT_DBDATE but package failed. It succeeded with DT_DATE Output type only to have all date columns as 1899-12-30. Do you guys know the right way to convert using script task maybe from DT_WSTR to DT_DBDATE?

Comment: Ok, this problem seems poorly defined. When you open the file and look at it in Excel does Excel report these cells as using `General` format or `Date` format? If it shows `General` format then those dates are stored as literal string values and you should be able to use `DateTime.ParseExact` to convert them for storage in SQL `date` columns. If, on the other hand, Excel reports these as using `Date` format then they're actually stored as numeric values. e.g.: `2020-06-11` would be stored as `43993` because it is 43993 days after `1899-12-30` which is Excel's epoch date.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sorry if I wasn't clear,  the cells in Ecxel are General format